# Embedding online video from http://api.liveviewtech.com using JavaScript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video, dojo, video-streaming

I am creating a javascript/HTML5 web application, I have only video link and fullPath.

**Link:** [http://api.liveviewtech.com/live_units/getPublicVideoStream/173/32%3Fwidth=300%26display_camera_status=0%26video_dom_id=videodiv](http://api.liveviewtech.com/live_units/getPublicVideoStream/173/32?width=300&display_camera_status=0&video_dom_id=videodiv)

**FullPath:** [getliveviewsimple.asp?liveviewurl=http://api.liveviewtech.com/live_units/getPublicVideoStream/173/32/600](http://getliveviewsimple.asp?liveviewurl=http://api.liveviewtech.com/live_units/getPublicVideoStream/173/32/600)

Both **Link** and **FullPath** refers the same video.

I am not sure how we can embed this video in javascript application.
We are free to use dojo too if there are any way to do it.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing I get to know this url are besically live video feeds.
which we can integrate using below code:

**Client side:**

```
var TIMEOUT = 2000;
var refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(2, 31));
  $('img#camera').attr('src', 'http://api.liveviewtech.com/live_units/getPublicVideoStream/173/32/600' + random);
}, TIMEOUT);
```

Source:https://github.com/rodowi/Paparazzo.js?files=1

hope this will help others too.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way is to setup an Iframe and load your Video/Livestream inside.

Have a look here : http://webkompetenz.wikidot.com/html-handbuch:eingebettete-frames

The dojox/AV is experimental and maybe not supported in dojo 2.0 so i would be careful by using this.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/av.html#dojox-av

Regards, Miriam